# Pause button on jquery countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery countdown and I need to put a stop button that when it's clicked, pause the countdown, appreciate the help!

```js
$('#startClock').click(function() {
  $('#siguiente').fadeOut();
  $('#startClock').hide();
  $('#count').fadeIn();
  var counter = 30;
  setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      $('#count').html('<p style="font-size:18px;">EXCELENTE!</p>')
      $('#siguiente').fadeIn();
      $('#startClock').fadeIn().text('REPETIR');
    }
  }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-icons">
  <span id="count">30</span>
  <a href="#flexiones" id="siguiente" class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-right">SIGUIENTE EJERCICIO</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `#startClock` element? I don't see it anywhere in your *HTML* code

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your interval in a variable and clear it like this:

```js
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){},1000);

clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```js
timer = setInterval(function(){ $("button").text(Number($("button").text())+1) }, 1000);

$("button").click(function(){
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Click on the button to stop the countdown!
<button>0</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 30
var interval;
$('#startClock').click(function(){
  $('#siguiente').fadeOut();
  $('#startClock').hide();
  $('#count').fadeIn();

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        $('#count').html('<p style="font-size:18px;">EXCELENTE!</p>')
        $('#siguiente').fadeIn();
        $('#startClock').fadeIn().text('REPETIR');
    }
  }, 1000);
});

$("#btnStopCounter").click(function(){
   clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Something like this ? First your counter needs to be global , so you can continue again after pausing it.

And you need interval to be saved inside variable so you can clear it on your stop counter function.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably do the trick

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 30;
    var running = false
    var timer = null;

   function setTimer(){
     running = true;
     timer = setInterval(function() {
     counter--;
        if (counter >= 0) {
           span = document.getElementById("count");
           span.innerHTML = counter;
        }
        if (counter === 0) {
           clearInterval(counter);
           $('#count').html('<p style="font-size:18px;">EXCELENTE!</p>')
           $('#siguiente').fadeIn();
           $('#startClock').fadeIn().text('REPETIR');
       }
     }, 1000);
  }


  $('#siguiente').on('click', function(){
     if(running){
       clearInterval(timer)
       running = false;
     } else {
       setTimer()
     }
   })


  $('#startClock').on('click', function(){
      setTimer();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some global variable for checking `start` or `stop` state

```
var Paused = false;
var counter = 30;
$('#startClock').click(function() {
  $('#siguiente').fadeOut();
  var text = (Paused) ? "Start":"Stop";
  $('#startClock').text(text);
  $('#count').fadeIn();
  Count();
});

function Count() {
    Paused = !Paused;
  setInterval(function() {
    if(Paused) {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      $('#count').html('<p style="font-size:18px;">EXCELENTE!</p>')
      $('#siguiente').fadeIn();
      $('#startClock').fadeIn().text('REPETIR');
    }
    }
  }, 1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't do it, I added a stop button with clearinterval and it doesn't do anything, check out all the code:

```
<span id="count">30</span>
        <a href="" id="stop">STOP</a>
        <a href="#flexiones" id="siguiente" class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-right">SIGUIENTE EJERCICIO</a>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer" style="background: #FFDA6F;">
    <a href="#" id="startClock" class="comenzar">COMENZAR</a>
  </div>


  $('#startClock').click(function(){
  $('#siguiente').fadeOut();
  $('#startClock').hide();
  $('#count').fadeIn();
  var counter = 30;
  var interval;
  internval = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        $('#count').html('<p style="font-size:18px;">EXCELENTE!</p>')
        $('#siguiente').fadeIn();
        $('#startClock').fadeIn().text('REPETIR');
    }

  }, 1000);

});

        $("#stop").click(function(){
     clearInterval(interval);
  });
```